# Unable to set array in useState hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is my code i am trying to set array in setUsers the data comes properly from backend but it does not get set in hook please help me

```
const LoadAllUser = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const loadUsers = () => {
    loadalluser()
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.error) {
          console.log(data.error);
          // setusers(data.error);
        } else {
          setUsers(data);
        }
      })
      .catch((eror) => console.log("error is here"));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadUsers();
  }, []);
```

My return look like this

```
return (
    <div>
      {users.length > 0 ? (
        users.map((index, user) => {
          return (
            <div key="index">
              <label>Name : {user.name}</label>
              <label>Email : {user.email}</label>
              <label>NUmber : {user.number}</label>
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <h1> No users found </h1>
      )}
      )
    </div>
  );
```

And this is how i fetch all of my users

```
export const loadalluser = (users) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/loadalluser`, {
    method: "GET",
    body: JSON.stringify(users),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
};
```

Comment: so, what does data have? console.log(data). also please provide more details

Comment: Did you make sure you don't have an error? What *does* happen?

Comment: i tried backend it is working perfectly in postman

Comment: yes i am sure i dont have error

Comment: so is my code perfect ?

Comment: Apostolos data has array of users which comes from database

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What does your return look like?

Comment: Please update the code in your question, so we can see it in proper formatting :)

Comment: @Apostolos in data i am fetching all the user from database

Comment: If you are checking for `data.error`, it appears that `data` is NOT an array. It's an object.

Comment: Can you do a console.log of `data.constructor.name`? If it's an array, it should log as `array`.

Comment: @Vasanth i am getting all the users from database and in console they come as object of users

Comment: Can you share a sample of that object of users?

Comment: Most likely, you might have to do Object.values(data).

Comment: @Vasanth can you tell me how to do that

Comment: If you update your question with your response object then it will be easier to help you, otherwise we can only assume it's an arbitrary object of arbitrary shape. Using `Object.values(response.pathToUserDataArray)` is about the best hint one can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` only rejects on cancelled requests or network errors, otherwise it returns a resolved Promise.

[Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

> A `fetch()` promise will reject with a `TypeError` when a network error is
> encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side, although this
> usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute
> a network error, for example. An accurate check for a successful
> `fetch()` would include checking that the promise resolved, then
> checking that the `Response.ok` property has a value of true.

You should check `response.ok` to ensure the request was successful or not. You can also likely also remove the catch block as any catch blocks in the consuming component code will catch them.

```
export const loadalluser = (users) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/loadalluser`, {
    method: "GET",
    body: JSON.stringify(users),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      return response.json();
    });
};
```

This change should help by *not* silently swallowing failed fetch requests and update state with bad values.

Also, do you need to pass `users` to `loadalluser` for the body of the GET request?